# Как лучше сделать стрелку?

Tags: css3, html5, mockup

Как Вам кажется, как лучше сделать данную стрелку вниз, картинкой, или при помощи CSS3. Кто знает, как можно это сделать на CSS3?

[image]

Comment: Можно сделать при помощи border. Попробуйте это: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/. Для такой задачи использовать SVG я бы не стал ;)

Comment: Олег Б, Большое спасибо! Хороший инструмент!